# DropDownListFor non selected and with requirer text

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

How can I do a @Html.DropDownListFor element non selected and with a requirer text without adding a new option element with that?

I have this code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Description, new SelectList(ViewBag.CarsDsc, "Id", "Description"), new { @class = "iEdit"})
```

but I want something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an overload for the method [`DropDownListFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703670%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), that accepts an option value `optionLabel`:

> The text for a default empty item. This parameter can be null.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Description, 
                      new SelectList(ViewBag.CarsDsc, "Id", "Description"), 
                      "-Please select one-",
                      new { @class = "iEdit"})
```

Comment: html attributes are expected to be placed after the Label option, no ?

Comment: @user3041160 - Yes, this is true, they should come after the option, like in this [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703670%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal that don't work to me, I got this error: "Cannot resolve method 'DropDownListFor(...... "

Comment: @Ninita - Sorry, see my edit, the html attributes should come after the option value.

Comment: Yes, I tried just 1 minute ago that and that work. I gonna answer you rigth now about that :) thanks